# Strange error from document library only when clicked from the WebPart

Tags: 2010, web-part, workflow

I have a document library using an OOB approval workflow in SharePoint 2010.

When I add the document library to my site home page as a WebPart I have added the field "Approval Workflow" to the WebPart view.

This field will display "In Progress" and should be linked to the approval workflow history..

However when I click it from the WebPart I get an error

> Error
>
> An unexpected error has occured.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: 17fc3fa6-70a2-46ab-9e8e-93dcb0fa8b70
>
> Date and Time: 5/7/2014 12:13:39 PM

Yet if I actually go into the document library and click this link it works properly.  So the error is only coming from the WebPart view?   Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can see if I copy both links the WebPart one is missing the anything for the "List" parameter.   Does anyone know why or how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Well.. after much Googling I found the answer on this page
http://www.danielroot.info/2010/07/obscure-sharepoint-2010-workflow-status.html

There are two possible solutions.

Solution 1:

> So, here’s the workaround until this is patched:
>
> Open the site in sharepoint designer, edit homepage (or, whatever page
>   has the issue) place the text cursor in the Workflow Status cell that
>   has the bug type ‘test’ – this is to break into custom xslt, and to
>   help you mark where to place the snippets. switch to split view find
>   the  that contains some xslt and the word ‘test’.  Your
>   cursor *should* be there already. Replace everything between the
>    with Snippet 2.  Add Snippet 1 to the bottom of the
>   stylesheet, immediately before   Remove the word
>   ‘test’ that you typed, if you didn’t replace it above Save Snippet 1
>
> ```
> <xsl:param name="text" />
>
> <xsl:param name="replace" />
>
> <xsl:param name="by" />
>
> <xsl:choose>
>
>   <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
>
>     <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
>
>     <xsl:value-of select="$by" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
>
>     <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
>
>       <xsl:with-param name="text"
>
>       select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
>
>       <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
>
>       <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
>
>     </xsl:call-template>
>
>   </xsl:when>
>
>   <xsl:otherwise>
>
>     <xsl:value-of select="$text" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
>
>   </xsl:otherwise>
>
> </xsl:choose>
> ```
>
> Snippet 2
>
> ```
>             <xsl:attribute name="height">100%</xsl:attribute>
>
>             <xsl:attribute name="onmouseover">OnChildItem(this)</xsl:attribute>
>
>   </xsl:if>
>
>             <xsl:attribute name="class">
>
>             <xsl:call-template name="getTDClassValue">
>
>                             <xsl:with-param name="class" select="$class" />
>
>                             <xsl:with-param name="Type" select="@Type"/>
>
>                             <xsl:with-param name="ClassInfo" select="@ClassInfo"/>
>
>             </xsl:call-template>
>
>   </xsl:attribute>
>
>   <xsl:variable name="workflowStatusLink">
>
>   <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="PrintFieldWithECB">
>
>     <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
>
>   </xsl:apply-templates>
>
>   </xsl:variable>
>
>   <xsl:variable name="workflowStatusLinkFixedUp">
>
> <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
>
>   <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$workflowStatusLink" />
>
>   <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'List='" />
>
>   <xsl:with-param name="by" select="''" />
>
> </xsl:call-template>
> ```
>
> ```
>   <xsl:value-of select="$workflowStatusLinkFixedUp" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
> ```

There is also a second solution that I found in the comments...

Solution 2:
Using SharePoint Designer, move the default.aspx homepage INTO the document library with the attached workflow.  Then set it as the homepage.

I tried both solutions and both worked.. however I didn't like the homepage being in the document library (just the way it altered the URL and breadcrumbs) so I went with the first solution.